# I found an item and it went to a weird spot on my screen. Now what?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

I found an item called Match Stick. After I picked it up, it went to a weird spot on my screen:

[image]

What makes this item so special that it gets to go to that part of my screen? How do I use it? Are there other items like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are part of a new item class called "Trinkets". They're like a mixture of useable items and passive items; the effect is always present, but you can only have one at a time. If you find another trinket and pick it up, you'll drop the one you have right now.

Answer (score 1):

Those are *Trinkets*. You can only have one at a time but if you find a item called *Mom's Purse* you can carry two of them. Mystical vending machines can sometimes drop these trinkets in exchange for coins. My own favourite trinket is Cancer.